# How can I add class on active li with JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li onclick="this.className='active'"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li onclick="this.className='active'"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li onclick="this.className='active'"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li onclick="this.className='active'"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I add active class on li tag with JavaScript. Here I am try to do it. It is working but not properly. I am doing for tabs here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, I guess you are expecting this:

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li a");
for (var i = 0, length = a.length; i < length; i++) {
  a[i].onclick = function() {
    var b = document.querySelector(".nav li.active");
    if (b) b.classList.remove("active");
    this.parentNode.classList.add('active');
  };
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #0f9;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how can I remove class with other li

Comment: @user3282537 For that you have to write a dedicated event listener. You can't do all the things here in an inline handler.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Added Event handler buddy.

Comment: @user3282537 Can you use jQuery, looks like you are using bootstrap?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think he is asking us to remove the active class for all the other li other than the clicked one.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yup. I understood.

Comment: I need to do it with  javascript

Comment: @user3282537 Give me a few mins, will make it.

Comment: @RayonDabre I am dumb. Corrected. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, It happens mate! `querySelector` would look better as you will not need `[0]` with that..And keep it in variable instead of selecting element twice..

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I hope you will not mind.. `className` will override the existing class if any..

Comment: @RayonDabre I know... `classList.remove()` and `classList.add()`

Comment: @PraveenKumar, Yes... Now it is better and will have less side effects.. :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have jquery

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
 .active {background-color: #0f9;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("ul.nav.nav-tabs").on('click', 'li', function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

---

Vanilla JavaScript (ES6 where I tested, might work on ES5)

```
const elm = document.querySelector('ul');
elm.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
  const elActive = elm.querySelector('.active');
  if (elActive) {
    elActive.removeAttribute('class');
  }
  el.target.setAttribute('class', 'active');
});
```

Comment: **No**. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250901/how-can-i-add-class-on-active-li-with-javascript-code/36250917?noredirect=1#comment60131632_36250917).

Comment:  I updated with Vanilla JavaScript. But I did mention `if you have jquery` and in my defense, I will say jQuery is JavaScript (it's a javascript library)

Comment: Wow, why such a long time later, updating this? Anyway, I'll give you a vote up if you feel good. 

Comment: Thanks, @PraveenKumarPurushothaman :-) I actually got a notification and when click, I end up here (not sure why ). I saw your comment and updated my answer. I hope it helps...

Comment: Awesome man, thanks a lot! 