# How to make active button in navigation bar change color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so i'm super beginner with html and css and i don't know javascript at all.I'm creating a little website as a school project, i made horizontal navigation bar from w3schools tutorial, what i want to do is when i press one of the buttons to stay colored, not just change color for 1 sec because they are 'active'. My code may be completely messy but i really need help.
Also i have 3 more subpages connected to this one, i want them to stay colored as well.

What i'm trying to achieve is exactly this: [How can I add class on active li with JavaScript code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250901/how-can-i-add-class-on-active-li-with-javascript-code)
But it doesnt work for me, maybe i need to change something in javascrip because my class is named 'navbar'?

I've tried several solves from this topic on stack overflow but none of these work for me :\

HTML:

```
    <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="sajt.html">Pocetna</a></li>
    <li><a href="sajt2.html">Stranica 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="sajt3.html">Stranica 3</a></li>
    <li style="float: right;"><a href="sajt4.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar li {
    float: left;
 }

 .navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

Im expecting link to stay orange when im on that page.

Comment: _“I've tried several solves from this topic on stack overflow but none of these work for me”_ - then please at least refer to the suggestions that you did try - link the questions, or show what you tried. Otherwise, no one here knows if they would not be referring to something you already tried, and that’s rather pointless.

Comment: I've tried some random javascript codes from people that had the same problem as me, i don't really know what they do and which one exactly they were.

Comment: _“Im expecting link to stay orange when im on that page.”_ - then you need to make that link, in that page, distinguishable from the other links somehow - for example by adding a class to it, when the user is on that particular page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46424941/ f.e. shows one way to do that. If you can not get it working this way, then you need to give us a _proper_ problem description though.

Comment: So if i understand well, i should add for example class 'tree' on first page on all <a> tags and then class 'dog' on second page on all <a> tags etc?

Answer (score 1):

you can do some things with jquery like add an event listener that changes the css of html elements

```
const changeColor = () => {
    $('ul > li > a').css('background-color', 'inherit')
    $(event.target).css("background-color", "red")
}

$('ul > li > a').on('click', changeColor)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z02ndowt/

Comment: This doesn't really works how i want it to work.If i press first tab then second and then third they will all be orange? I wan't only the active tab to change color.

Comment: i added a hacky fix to implement the behavior you are describing. should be closer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a class onto your html `<a>` tag on the link that is active and then just style the active class within your CSS. See below:

HTML

```
<ul class="navbar">
      <li><a class="active" href="sajt.html">Pocetna</a></li>
      <li><a href="sajt2.html">Stranica 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="sajt3.html">Stranica 3</a></li>
      <li style="float: right;"><a href="sajt4.html">Kontakt</a></li>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
.active {
    color: orange;
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly the same as on w3schools but that doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong but without more context and code we cannot see what is wrong. Are your other styles being applied?

Comment: I have one more unordered list but it has its own class and only font size and font family so i think it can not really make something wrong?

Comment: My question was are the other styles you have applied being applied to you other list? If not then it would suggest you have not linked your stylesheet within your HTML document. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: CSS document is linked for sure, these styles that i pasted are the only ones that goes with the list (.navbar class) I also have some more styles that stands for other things such as text and they work properly.

Comment: Where are you applying the active class within your HTML?

Comment: Sorry, i don't really understand your question. Im applying class 'navbar' only to that <ul> and on other 3 navbars that are exactly the same on 3 other pages, but i should also tell you that i have 4 pages sharing same css file

Comment: You need to have the class 'active' added within your html on the <a> tag as I have showed you within my answer. You then need to style this class with your CSS, again as I have showed you within my answer. I am asking where you are applying the 'active' class within the HTML. Is it on your <li> tag or on the <a> tag for example? Also I am not too sure why you have down voted my answer as if you are linking your stylesheet correctly then this code WILL work.

Comment: I added class active on my <a> tags, all of them, on all 4 pages.To make sure its not something else that makes it not working, i created new web page without content and just navbar, but it still doesn't work, i think i'm doing something wrong but everything is exactly the same as you replied.

Comment: The only other thing I would suggest then is to try deleting your browser cache. Otherwise I cannot help anymore without more code

Comment: If you don't mind i can maybe upload entire folder with all 4 pages and .css document and then you can check is there something wrong?

Comment: There is no real need for that. If you go to https://codepen.io/ and add your HTML and CSS I can take a look

Comment: https://codepen.io/simic21/pen/KKKwMEE    So this is the main page but keep in mind that i have 3 more that are connected to 'Stranica 2' 'Stranica 3' which are basically empty they only have navigation bar and text above it. I also have 'Kontakt' which is some fleshy CSS portfolio-like page i can link it in another codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i did some testing and kinda found a solution. I put identificator on  instead of class. So on my main page i put id="active" on first link, on my second page on second link etc. then just added #active { background-color: orange; } and it works just how i wanted it to work.